# Footer background-color not showing up

Tags: html, colors, background-color, footer

I used background-color but the color didn't show up

i tried typing

```
<footer style="background-color: hsl(0 18% 81%)">
```

and i was expecting it to change the color of the background but it didn't.
thank you to anyone who would like to help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to close footer and put somthing inside:

```
    <footer style="background-color: hsl(0, 18%, 81%)">
      <h1>footer</h1>
    </footer>
```